# VBScript: how do I use a a regular expression Replace to add a newline?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a string which is a long single line.  I want to add a newline after every match I find; in this example I'm searching for "foo"

I can successfully find all instances of "foo" and trigger a replacement:

```
    strText="stufffoobarbazfoofoomorestuff"
    Set reZap = New RegExp
    reZap.Global  = True
    reZap.Pattern = "(foo)"
    strNewText = reZap.Replace(strText, "$1\n")
```

The problem is this just inserts "\n" into the string so I end up with "stufffoo\nbarbazfoo\nfoo\nmorestuff"  when what I really want is

"stufffoo
barbazfoo
foo
morestuff"

How do I get Replace to add a newline?

Comment: I presume that you'd need a `CR` as well.  Try `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, the trick is to use vbCrLf instead of regexp's \n:

```
    strNewText = reZap.Replace(strText, "$1" & vbCrLf )
```